# Is it possible for Outlook on a domain-joined PC to recognize the logged in AD user and automatically complete their name, email and password?

Tags: microsoft-outlook-2010, exchange

Is it possible for Outlook on a domain PC to recognize the logged in Active Directory user and automatically set up their email account (i.e. entering their name, email address and password) the first time it is run under that AD user's account?

I believe I saw this functionality when working in the office of a local ISP (where we would sometimes have to use Outlook on different workstations that we had never signed in to previously); however, a Microsoft rep I spoke to recently was convinced that Outlook does not have this feature.

N.b. I am not referring to Outlook autodicover (we are already using that but users still need to fill in their name, email and password the first time they use a new workstation).

Our environment consists of Outlook 2010 clients connected to Exchange Online through Office 365.

Does anyone know if such a feature exists?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, this is possible.

You do need Office 2010 or higher, auto-discover and a domain policy.

The user will still get a screen to setup the account, but the fields should be filled in and only need to press continue.

If auto-discover is failing however, it will default back to making the user fill in the stuff themselves.

So keep in mind, that auto-discover is usually used to point from outside to the server, and that a network from the inside may not follow the autodiscover unless you route that traffic internally (dns server)

Comment: We have Outlook 2010 on all workstations and have autodiscover working perfectly. It sounds like we just need this domain policy (Group Policy?) Do you know the name of this policy or of some online documentation which explains how to configure it?

Comment: Group policy, yes. I don't know it from the back of my head. We had to manage this for one of our clients once, and had to research it then. I'd have to search for it again now.